# Node.js, Using single readline to read multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js

After learning Ruby on Rails I wanted also learn Node.JS.

In Node.JS you can read files line by line by using `readline`:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var readline = require("readline");

var fileName =  "input.txt";
```

We can assign `readline` to file in this way:

```
var lineReader = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
});
```

Then we can read each line like this:

```
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
   // handle line code here
});
```

This will allow me to read only single file.

If I have array of filenames like this:

```
var fileNames = ["input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt"];
```

I want to read each lines of each files in this array and handle their `line` events.

How is it possible to read line by line multiple files?

Comment: "*read line by line multiple files at the same time*" - what does that even mean? How would that work? How will you code it so you know where each line comes from? And, although I'm not a Ruby guy, is that possible there?

Comment: Line reading is not a feature if JavaScript or Node. Whatever the package you use lets you do is limited only by that package. You're always welcome to contribute and extend existing packages it create your own. Either way, questions asking for external libraries are off topic.

Comment: @Amit `readline` is a default Node.js module: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: @SlashmanX - haa! do you happen to know how far back does it go? (I've never noticed it)

Comment: @Amit - Since v0.5 at least: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.0/api/readline.html. It was in v.04 but not documented it seems: https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/readline.html

Comment: As I understand the question it is about how to read line 1 of file X, then line 1 of file Y, then line 1 of file Z, then line 2 of file X, etc. Is this correct, @QQQ?

Comment: @SlashmanX - yep. I guess I never looked for something like that. My bad. QQQ - my apologies.

Comment: @Amit - I actually only discovered it the other day. I was the same, never had a need to look for something like that

Comment: @Amit, Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loop through the array, create a `ReadStream` and handle the `line` event:

```
var fileNames = ["input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt"];
var lineReader = [];

for(var x in fileNames) {
    var fileName = fileNames[x];

    lineReader[x] = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
    });

    lineReader[x].on('line', function(line) {
        // handle line of every fileName
    });
}
```

Comment: Can we read 1st line from all files, then 2nd lines from all files, and so on? That would be a more useful real life scenario. Thank you